# Mapping Entire Drive Into A Tree View

Tags: c#

I need help on how to map my drives into a tree view. I can get my drives to show but I can not get all the sub directories. I would like to get my entire drive mapped out into a tree view. Any help would be appreciated. This is what I got so far.

```
        string[] drives = Environment.GetLogicalDrives();
        foreach (string dr in drives)
        {
            TreeNode node = new TreeNode(dr);
            node.Tag = dr;
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
        }
        treeView1.CollapseAll();
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet2591.htm  You will have to modify your existing code to recursively visit each drive

Comment: Your code doesn't even try to dig through the subdirectories.  Louis showed you how but beware that this can take a LONG time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a lazy loading version:

```
private void fillTree() { 
  string[] drives = Environment.GetLogicalDrives();
  foreach(string dr in drives) {
    TreeNode node = new TreeNode(dr);
    node.Tag = dr;
    node.ImageIndex = 0; // drive icon
    node.Tag = dr;
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
    node.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("?"));
  }
  treeView1.BeforeExpand += new TreeViewCancelEventHandler(treeView1_BeforeExpand);
}

void treeView1_BeforeExpand(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e) {
  if((e.Node.Nodes.Count == 1) && (e.Node.Nodes[0].Text=="?")) {
    RecursiveDirWalk(e.Node);
  }
}

private TreeNode RecursiveDirWalk(TreeNode node) {
  string path = (string)node.Tag;
  node.Nodes.Clear();
  string[] dirs = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path);
  for(int t = 0; t < dirs.Length; t++) {
    TreeNode n = new TreeNode(dirs[t].Substring(dirs[t].LastIndexOf('\\')+1));
    n.ImageIndex = 1; // dir icon
    n.Tag = dirs[t];
    node.Nodes.Add(n);
    n.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("?"));
  }

  // Optional if you want files as well:
  string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path);
  for(int t = 0; t < files.Length; t++) {
    TreeNode tn = new TreeNode(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(files[t]));
    tn.Tag = files[t];
    tn.ImageIndex = 2; // file icon
    node.Nodes.Add(tn);
  } // end of optional file part

  return node;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To do it recursively:

```
private void fillTree() { // you allready had most of this
  string[] drives = Environment.GetLogicalDrives();
  foreach(string dr in drives) {
    TreeNode node = RecursiveDirWalk(dr);
    node.ImageIndex = 0; // drive icon
    node.Tag = dr;
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
  }
}

// now add this
private TreeNode RecursiveDirWalk(string path) {
  TreeNode node = new TreeNode(path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf('\\')));
  node.ImageIndex = 1; // dir icon
  node.Tag = path;
  string[] dirs = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path);
  for(int t = 0; t < dirs.Length; t++) {
    node.Nodes.Add(RecursiveDirWalk(dirs[t]));
  }

  // Optional if you want files as well:
  string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path);
  for(int t = 0; t < files.Length; t++) {
    TreeNode tn = new TreeNode(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(files[t]));
    tn.Tag = files[t];
    tn.ImageIndex = 2; // file icon
    node.Nodes.Add(tn);
  } // end of optional file part

  return node;
}
```

Comment: After adding @Louis Somers code to do it recursively, there is no longer anything displayed in my tree view. Maybe im doing something wrong. I dont know

Comment: I think you'd be better served to simply load it as people drill down.  This way you would only build the tree one level at a time; two if you wanted to display summary detail at the parent levels.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code used to display a tree with only the drives shown at first, adding to the tree as the user clicks on the nodes. This code will not display empty drives. Adding icons to each node is left as an exercise for the student:

```
    private static string PLACEHOLDER = "...";

    private void ListDrives()
    {
        string[] drives = Environment.GetLogicalDrives();
        foreach (string drive in drives)
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(drive))
            {
                TreeNode node = new TreeNode(drive);
                node.Tag = drive;
                this.treeViewFolders.Nodes.Add(node);
                node.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(PLACEHOLDER));
            }
        }
        this.treeViewFolders.BeforeExpand += new TreeViewCancelEventHandler(treeView_BeforeExpand);
    }

    void treeView_BeforeExpand(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0)
        {
            if (e.Node.Nodes[0].Text == PLACEHOLDER)
            {
                e.Node.Nodes.Clear();
                string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(e.Node.Tag.ToString());
                foreach (string dir in dirs)
                {
                    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
                    TreeNode node = new TreeNode(di.Name);
                    node.Tag = dir;
                    try
                    {
                        if (di.GetDirectories().GetLength(0) > 0)
                            node.Nodes.Add(null, PLACEHOLDER);
                    }
                    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
                    {
                        // TODO: update node images
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ExplorerForm", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        e.Node.Nodes.Add(node);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```